# Looping through characters in Perl

Tags: perl, for-loop

I'm having quite a difficulty, figuring out some strange behavior when looping through symbols in Perl, using the `for` loop.
This code snippet works just as expected:

```
for (my $file = 'a'; $file le 'h'; $file++) {
    print $file;
}
```

#### Output: abcdefgh

But when I try the loop through the symbols backward, like this:

```
for (my $file = 'h'; $file ge 'a'; $file--) { 
    print $file;
}
```

gives me the following as a result.

#### Output: h

Maybe the decrement operator doesn't behave as I think it does when symbols are involved?

Does anybody have any ideas on the matter? I'd really appreciate your help!

Regards,

Tommy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The auto-decrement operator is not magical, as per [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)

You can do something like this though:

```
for my $file (reverse 'a' .. 'h') { 
    print $file;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the auto-decrement operator got me fooled.
Your solution works perfectly!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In perl, the (++) increment operator is *magical*, whereas the decrement operator [is not](http://www.chankeypathak.com/2011/06/perl-increment-operator-is-magical.html) ...

as alternative to Eric's modification, you could simply do:

```
for (my $file = 'h'; $file ge 'a';  $file=chr((ord$file)-1)) { 
    print $file;
}
```

for counting the characters down.

Answer (score 2):

The '++' operator is magical to work on strings in interesting ways.  The Camel, 3rd edition, page 91, gives these examples:

```
print ++($foo = '99'); # prints '100'
print ++($foo = 'a0'); # prints 'b1'
print ++($foo = 'Az'); # prints 'Ba'
print ++($foo = 'zz'); # prints 'aaa'
```

The '--' operator does not have this magic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the magic behavior is only for auto-increment:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement --> "The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it."